# Left alignment of last line of flex cells

Tags: css, flexbox

I've made a table-like flex structure, that looks pretty nice and has adaptive number of cells, but when last row isn't full - it stretches remaining cells to full size, which looks unshapely. 
[image]

https://jsfiddle.net/zzmaster/6uw4gm3t/3/
(you need to enlarge results area to maximum in order to see this)

Logically, `justify-content: flex-start;` should fix this, but it doesn't.

Is there any way to turn remained cells back to their's place?

Comment: Should the columns have a fixed width or fluid?

Answer (score 1):

You can fix with remove `flex: 1 1 0px` CSS style. Replace below code with your current code.

```
ul.text { 
  display: flex; 
  justify-content: flex-start; 
  flex-wrap: wrap; 
} 

ul.text li { 
  min-width: 300px; 
  display: inline-flex; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

change your css like below!

```css
ul.text {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-start;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
ul.text li {
  min-width: 300px;
  display: inline-flex;
  flex: 1 1 0px;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  resize: both;
}
```